# paperclip url to return asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

i'm searching for a solution to get the absolute url with asset_host of a paperclip object. the url method only returns the relative url. so i tried this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
  :url => "#{ActionController::Base.asset_host.call(nil, request)}/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
})
```

but the request is missing in the initializer. or how do i get it?

my asset_host config looks like this:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new do |source, request|
  if request.ssl?
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  else
    "http://cdn.somehost.com"
  end
end
```

i'm stuck with this!

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a somewhat complicated solution, but you could do it like this, first use a before_filter to set a variable that will hold if a request is SSL or not:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_current_request
  after_filter :unset_current_request

  protected

  def set_current_request
    Thread.current[:current_request] = request
  end

  def unset_current_request
    Thread.current[:current_request] = nil
  end         

end
```

With this defined, you'll have to define a Paperclip interpolation:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :assets_host  do |attachment, style|
  request = Thread.current[:current_request]
  if request.ssl?
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  else
    "http://cdn.somehost.com"
  end
end
```

Then you can include this interpolation at your config:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
  :url => ":assets_host/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
})
```

I haven't done this exactly like this, but I have used interpolations many times (and that's also how the S3 storage does it's magic), so it should work.

Comment: Great! I think there is no need to block when in and out of the controller. Instead I did a View Helper using `#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}`

Comment: you need a work around to make it work under non-request environment, like delayed email, background job, ...

Comment: just wondering why need to thread variable instead instance variable?